# Bootstrap calendar not getting reset on clicking in datetime textbobox

Tags: jquery, reset, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap date-picker by ref. the below link https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

but I found a bug

1. Open calendar by click inside the textbox.
2. Go to next month or previous month.
3. Click on outside the calendar and get it closed.
4. open the calendar again.
   It is observed that current month is not coming and previously clicked month is coming.

How i can reset the datepicker to current month or the date which i have selected.

Using below code but its not working in focus-in event

```
$(this).focusin(function () {
    $('.dateCal2').datepicker('update', $('.dateCal2').val());
});
```